# TabBarController's frame is affected by modal popup

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I modified the stock tab bar project, changing the frame of the tabbarcontroller so I could insert an iAd frame to persist throughout the app. I did this in the method: (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions.

This works until a modal popup is introduced. When a modal popup is removed from the view, the tabbarcontroller's frame has been restored to it's original height, that is, the application's frame.

How can I maintain the desired frame? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your tab bar controller isn't the main view controller of the window.

You want to add the tab bar controller and the iAd view as siblings to the window object, or define another view controller that owns both, setting up the layout of its view either in a xib or in -loadView. Hope this puts you in the right direction.

Comment: @SoldOutActivist How did you end up doing it?

Comment: I already had UIView animation functionality to toggle the ad for various reasons like the network is down, or has come back up; just like Apple wants you to do. I decided that when a modal popup is present, the ad shouldn't think it's being shown (even if the ad knows this), so I slide it out of the way as the modal window appears. By using my already present functionality, I could better control the flow of ads and solve my problem.